# Reading PDF file in Classic asp Getting 'This site can not be reached' error message

Tags: asp-classic, abcpdf

I am trying to load pdf file in classic asp site for that using ABCpdf.dll
I am getting error **This site can’t be reached**

The connection was reset.
Try:
Reloading the page
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

It does not showing any console error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V02SP.png)

Thanks(version 8)

Comment: ABCpdf uses the version of Internet Explorer installed on the server to generate a pdf.  Basically it's the printing an IE screen to a pdf file. This is why you need to specify absolute urls with the component  If possible you need to open a remote desktop session with your server and look at the security settings on IE.

Comment: It's an awful component, only one I'll use and swear by is [Persists.Pdf](http://www.asppdf.com/) it's not free but you get what you pay for. Best bit about it no dependencies!

Comment: Completely agree with @Lankymart, use Persists AspPdf. I've used it for years, and it's never let me down. Their support is second to none.

Comment: thanks friends for valuable suggestions. but We already have licensed for ABCpdf  7.